# Bind complex object model to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I need to bind a complex object(model) to the view. I have a search model and search view..

Search Model,

```
public class SearchModel
{
    public SearchCriteria SearchCriteria { get; set; }
    .....
}
```

Search Criteria

```
public class SearchCriteria
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    ......
}
```

Search View

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.SearchCriteria.AccountId, "Account ID")
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SearchCriteria.AccountId)
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.SearchCriteria.AccountName, "Account Name")
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SearchCriteria.AccountName)
```

This is rendered as

```
<label for="SearchCriteria_AccountId">Account ID</label>
<input id="SearchCriteria_AccountId" name="SearchCriteria.AccountId" type="text" value="">
<label for="SearchCriteria_AccountName">Account Name</label>
<input id="SearchCriteria_AccountName" name="SearchCriteria.AccountName" type="text" value="">
```

control name is rendering as `SearchCriteria.AccountId`, `SearchCriteria.AccountName` and control id is rendering as `SearchCriteria_AccountId` , `SearchCriteria_AccountName`

and when submitting the form in get request,
querystring will be looks like,

```
?SearchCriteria.AccountId=1&SearchCriteria.AccountName=aaa
```

**Is there any way to change them to display without `SearchCriteria` suffix?**

so
control name should render as `AccountId`, `AccountName` and control id should render as `AccountId` , `AccountName`

and querystring should looks like,

```
?AccountId=1&AccountName=aaa
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change that if you want MVC to do the automated binding. You could of course provide your own name if you wanted. However, a more recommended approach would be to build a `ViewModel` like this:

```
public class SearchViewModel
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

that flattened the complex model. The reason this is the recommended approach is because a `View` isn't really a *complex model*, it's simply a *view* of a more complex underlying model. You could then use an [auto mapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) to very easily map the flattened `ViewModel` back into the *complex model* at the very top of your controller method.

Comment: You mean my `SearchCriteria` object will become `SearchViewModel` and it is bind to the `Search` view instead of `SearchModel`. and then map `SearchViewModel` to `SearchModel` in the `SearchController`?

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal, yep, that's exactly what I'm saying! Often times your *data model* is much more complex (e.g. hierarchical) than the view itself. Keep it simple for yourself and provide the view with a *view model* that it can use and bind to.

Comment: Do you have any idea about what will happen to the Data Annotation in the model?

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal, yeah, it won't get replicated. You'll need to annotate the *view model*.